# 2d array of zeros

Tags: python

There is no array type in python, but to emulate it we can use lists. I want to have 2d array-like structure filled in with zeros. My question is: what is the difference, if any, in this two expressions:

```
zeros = [[0 for i in xrange(M)] for j in xrange(M)]
```

and

```
zeros = [[0]*M]*N
```

Will `zeros` be same? which one is better to use by means of speed and readability?

Comment: this form `zeros = [[0]*M]*N` will NOT get you want you want because each row will be an instance, so modifying any column will change that column in all rows!  if M and N are 3, `zeros[0][1]=2` will result in `[[0,2,0],[0,2,0],[0,2,0]]`

Comment: Related: [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](/q/240178/4518341) (covers why not to use `[[0]*M]*N`)

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You should use [`numpy.zeros`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html).  If that isn't an option, you want the first version.  In the second version, if you change one value, it will be changed elsewhere in the list -- e.g.:

```
>>> a = [[0]*3]*3
>>> a
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> a[0][0] = 1
>>> a
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

This is because (as you read the expression from the inside out), you create a list of 10 zeros.  You then create a list of 10 references to that initial list of 10 zeros.

---

Note that this will also work and it avoids the nested list comprehension:

```
zeros = [ [0]*M for _ in range(N) ]
```

If `numpy` isn't on the table, this is the form I would use.

(Use `xrange` if you're still stuck in the python2.x dark ages :).)

Comment: Is it really necessary to use numpy simply for that single feature? +1 for first version.

Comment: @johnthexiii -- Possibly not.  But, if the OP wants a 2d array of zeros, I would be willing to go out on a limb and say that OP's code could probably benefit from numpy in other places as well.

Comment: i won't install numpy for just zeroing the list ;) Thanks for later explanation, it was what i was looking for.

Comment: i wouldn't use the above solution since this creates references as mentioned by others as well. i tried using this approach while initializing an output matrix for matrix multiplication result and the results were wrong due to the reference issue

Comment: @Nitin Are you talking about the form `[[0]*M]*N`? They're saying **not** to use that. I just edited to make it more readable, if that helps.

Comment: as of python 3 a = [[0]*3]*3 it will not work as array reference will be copied and changing one value will be reflect in all other copied data

Answer (score 53):

for Python 3 (no more xrange), the preferred answer

```
zeros = [ [0] * N for _ in range(M)]
```

for M x N array of zeros

Comment: I was taking a Python online exam just now, and for whatever reason, the correct answer was `zeros = [[0 for _ in range(N)] for _ in range(M)]`, whereas Zhe Hu's answer didn't give me full marks. Beats me, his version is 4 times faster.

Comment: His version creates references so if you changed a value, it will change in all rows as explained in the comments above.

Comment: @AnmolJagetia This list comprehension won't create `M` references to the same `[0]*N` list; it will create `M` such lists, and you shouldn't see mutations of one row affecting any others. In a list comprehension, e.g. `[expr for _ in range(M)]`, `expr` is evaluated `M` times, which in this case results in `M` lists being created. Meanwhile, `[expr]*M` will evaluate `expr` once, thereby creating `M` references to whatever `expr` evaluates to (`[0]*N` is a non-issue since 0 is an immutable primitive that will be copied).

Answer (score 25):

In second case you create a list of references to the same list. If you have code like:

```
[lst] * N
```

where the `lst` is a reference to a list, you will have the following list:

```
[lst, lst, lst, lst, ..., lst]
```

But because the result list contains references to the same object, if you change a value in one row it will be changed in all other rows.

Answer (score 5):

Zhe Hu's answer is the safer one and should have been the best answer. This is because if we use the accepted answer method

```
a = [[0] * 2] * 2
a[0][0] = 1
print(a)
```

will give the answer

```
[[1,0],[1,0]]
```

So even though you just want to update the first row first column value, all the values in the same column get updated. However

```
a = [[0] * 2 for _ in range(2)]
a[0][0] = 1
print(a)
```

gives the correct answer

```
[[1,0],[0,0]]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
time = np.arange(0,12,2)
N = [np.zeros_like(time) for _ in range(2)]
print(N)
```

Result:

```
[array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])]
```

```
N[0][1] = 2
print(N)
```

Result:

```
[array([0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])]
```

If we want the length of the array N to be same as of another array S, say, then:

```
N = [np.zeros_like(time) for _ in range(len(S))]
```

In this way we can have two arrays S and N where each element in S will have a corresponding array-element in N. For ex., S=[1-30:days in a month] and N=[hourly temperature for each day: 30 such arrays]. This N can be initialized just like above.