# List index out of range in 2D list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I understand that there are similar questions to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798796/python-list-index-out-of-range-error), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157961/2d-array-of-zeros). The first one addresses 1D lists, the second is great except it doesn't seem to work, and the third is close, but I still don't quite understand my issue.

Here is what I am trying to do. I need to create an 2D list (a 2D array in java and C++, which I am much more familiar with) filled with 0's. It needs to be size 20 across and 15 down.

Here is what I have tried:

```
self.grid = [[0 for x in range(GRID_COLUMN_SIZE)] for y in range(GRID_ROW_SIZE)] # where GRID_ROW_SIZE = 15, GRID_COLUMN_SIZE = 20
```

*Note*, I tried with the two constants switched (`COLUMN` first, then `ROW`), and it broke slightly later. In addition, I print the 2D list out and it's the wrong dimensions (15 across and 20 down).

Here is my later use of `self.grid`. Without getting too deep, I am iterating through all the values of the list (`grid`) and getting the surrounding points.

```
def populatePaths(self):
    for row in range(len(self.grid)):
        for column in range(len(self.grid[row])):
            if self.isPointAccessible(column, row):
                self.addPaths(column, row)

def addPaths(self, x, y):
    key = Point(x, y)
    print "Each: %s" % (key.toString())
    points = key.getSurroundingPoints()
    self.removeBarriersFromPath(points)
    self.paths[key] = points # a map from Points to lists of surrounding Points
```

Basically, I remove points along the path that can't be reached:

```
def removeBarriersFromPath(self, path):
    for point in list(path):
        print "Surrounding %s" % (point.toString())
        if not self.isPointAccessible(point.x, point.y):
            path.remove(point)
    return path
```

`self.isPointAccessible()` is trivial, but this is where it breaks. It checks to see if the value at the `(x,y)` location is 0: `return self.grid[x][y] == 0`

I added these print statements (`point.toString()` returns `(x,y)`) to show me the points as they happen, and I am able to iterate until `x==14`, but it breaks at `x==15`.

I suspect that I am getting the column/row order in the looping incorrect, but I'm not sure when/how.

Let me know if I didn't explain something clearly enough.

**Edit** Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nu/catkin_ws/src/apriltags_intrude_detector/scripts/sphero_intrude_gui.py", line 70, in start
    self.populatePaths()
  File "/home/nu/catkin_ws/src/apriltags_intrude_detector/scripts/sphero_intrude_gui.py", line 156, in populatePaths
    self.addPaths(column, row)
  File "/home/nu/catkin_ws/src/apriltags_intrude_detector/scripts/sphero_intrude_gui.py", line 162, in addPaths
    self.removeBarriersFromPath(points)
  File "/home/nu/catkin_ws/src/apriltags_intrude_detector/scripts/sphero_intrude_gui.py", line 168, in removeBarriersFromPath
    if not self.isPointAccessible(point.x, point.y):
  File "/home/nu/catkin_ws/src/apriltags_intrude_detector/scripts/sphero_intrude_gui.py", line 173, in isPointAccessible
    return self.grid[x][y] == 0
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Where does it break? Can you post the traceback?

Comment: I neglected to put that part in. It now contains the traceback as well as the information about where it breaks (`self.isPointAccessible`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not post the whole source for `isPointAccessible` but from the error message it looks like your return line must be:

```
return self.grid[y][x] == 0
```

since `y` denotes the row number and `x` is the column.

Comment: Oh! that was it! Btw, `return self.grid[x][y] == 0` was the entire method.